# Auto login user after email verification (Express/passport)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I would like to make it so after the user clicks their email verification link they are automatically logged in.

How can I go about this?

**Edit:** It was as simple as

```
req.session.passport.user = newUser._id
```

Apparently all passport does is assign the user ID to a user session, so doing it manually did the trick. Then just redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: Many ways really.

Answer (score 0):

Look into deep-linking.

You need to redirect the user when they click activate (uri to app or url to a website). This can be done with Express's redirect function.

For apps, there is a scheme tied to the app (ex. myapp://) which opens the app if you have it installed. In that case, whatever payload you sent (authentication information) can be listened for and handled to log the user in automatically.

For websites, you need to redirect them to a url along with their authentication information. You'll be listening for that as well, and log the user in automatically on your website.

Comment: Thanks Dan - is for a website, I am struggling with login in the user - passport login (http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/) has not been working out for me and gives me the error " Failed to serialize user into session" (although login in normally works). I am looking into maybe submitting the login form internally once the uses verified their account but have not found a way to do it :(

Comment: I am not familiar with passportjs. What I did was (1) when the user clicks the verification email, their account status is marked as activated. (2) A session token is generated for them. (3) They are redirected to the website with that token. (4) The site sees that token and sets their credentials to that token and signs them in.